# Graphs of functions defined by convolution

Tags: graphing-functions, convolution

A sequence of functions on the real line is defined as

$$f_0=\chi_{[-1,1]},\qquad f_{n+1}=f_n*f_0, n=0,1,2,\dots $$
Here * means convolution.
I tried to draw the graphs of the functions and see what happens to the graphs. But, it is too hard to draw the graph of each $f_n$. Could anyone tell me what kind of changes to the graphs as $n$ increases?

Answer (score 0):

It will tend towards a (scaled) Gaussian distribution function; see the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). If we scale $\chi$ so that $\int\chi(x)dx=1$ then we get the following sequence of functions (for the first 10)
[image]

Comment: Wow beautiful...